# Why isn't the derivative of $y = \sqrt{11}u+\sqrt{15u}$ equal to $11^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}(15u)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of $y = \sqrt{11}u+\sqrt{15u}$.

Since the sum rule states (if $f$ and $g$ are functions) $f + g = f' + g'$.

$$\frac{d}{du} \sqrt{11}u = 11^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\frac{d}{du} \sqrt{15u} = \frac{d}{du}(15u)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}(15u)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

but..

$$\frac{d}{du}\sqrt{11}u+\sqrt{15u} \neq 11^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}(15u)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think your answer is wrong? Perhaps your mistake is that when you differentiated $\sqrt{15u}$ you forgot to take the $\sqrt{15}$ factor out and it ended up in the denominator. In this case your answer should be $\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{\frac{15}{4u}}$

Another possibility is merely that $u=u(x)$ is a notation for a function which depends on some variable $x$ and that you are expected to differentiate with regards to $x$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "function of x"? Is there a way I can tell whether $\sqrt{11}u + \sqrt{15u}$ is a function of x?

Comment: @LuminousNutria It doesn't matter at all if $u$ is a function of $x$ since you are looking for the derivative of $y$ with respect to $u$ and there is no mention of any $x$ whatsoever.

Comment: I'm using an online math website for class work. It's the thing telling me that my input is wrong. I'm sure I put in the same stuff as in my question here.

Comment: @LuminousNutria What is the website you are u using? What is it telling you? Maybe it expects you to use the letter $x$ for the variable.

Comment: @LuminousNutria: I have given you a possible answer please tell me if it is right

Comment: My mistake. Your answer $\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{\frac{15}{4u}}$ *DOES* work. I put it in wrong the first time.

Comment: Did you use the chain rule to come up with $\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{\frac{15}{4u}}$?

Comment: @LuminousNutria :All I used was the rule for differentiating the power function $u^r$ for real $r$ namely $\frac{d}{du}u^r$=$ru^{r-1}$ so $\frac{d}{du}\sqrt{u}$=$\frac{d}{du}u^{\frac{1}{2}}$=$\frac{1}{2}u^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ so no chain rule

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{\text d}{\text d u}\sqrt{15u} = \frac{\text d (\sqrt{15u})}{\text d (15u)} \frac{\text d (15u)}{\text d u}$$

This is called the chain rule.

Another thing you can do is

$$\frac{\text d}{\text d u}(\sqrt{15u}) = \frac{\text d}{\text d u}(\sqrt{15}\sqrt u) = \sqrt{15} \cdot \frac{\text d\sqrt u}{\text d u}$$

Comment: What rule are you using there?

Comment: @LuminousNutria Chain rule.

Comment: I am not familiar with that usage of the chain rule. I could do something like $\frac{d}{dx}(-2x+12)^2 = -4(-2x+12)$ but this is new.